# Selenium webdriver xpath filtering

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

What is wrong with my xpath syntax? The nodes that I am trying to filter through are and my code is:

```
div class="cmeTableBlockWrapper cmeContentSection cmeContentGroup"
table id="quotesFuturesProductTable1" 
tr[1:]
   td id="quotesFuturesProductTable1_ZCZ4_last"
   td id="quotesFuturesProductTable1_ZCZ4_change"
   td id="quotesFuturesProductTable1_ZCZ4_priorSettle"

url = "http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/agricultural/grain-and-oilseed/corn.html"

driver = webdriver.Chrome() 

driver.get(url) 

table = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[class="cmeTableBlockerWrapper cmeContentSection cmeContentGroup"]/table[@id="quotesFuturesProductTable1"]') 

# or table = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//td[contains(div[@class="fixedpage_heading"], "CORN")]/table[@class="homepage_quoteboard"]')

for row in table.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')[1:]:  
    priorsettle = str(row.find_element_by_id('quotesFuturesProductTable1_ZSX4_priorSettle').text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the table [by `id`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_id), get the appropriate row by index (easiest way here):

```
table = driver.find_element_by_id('quotesFuturesProductTable1')
for row in table.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')[2:]:
    print row.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')[4].text
```

Prints (`Prior Settle` column):

```
338'2
350'6
359'2
366'2
374'0
384'2
393'6
400'4
404'4
402'0
402'0
418'2
407'4
```

Note that we need to skip 2 rows, not a single one, since there are two `tr` tags before the actual table content starts.